# Unable to locate header image in r markdown without specifying full path

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I want to specify the current working directory of R for location of header file. If i dont specify full path it doesnt work. But i wanted it in the same place where my rmd (same file as my R working directory) is located. The png file is present in the same place as my rmd file .

```
---
title: ""
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lipsum} 
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \fancyhead[]{\includegraphics[width=15cm]{pic.png}}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
- \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
- \fancyfoot{} 
- \fancyfoot[L]{Confidential - Restricted Usage }
- \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}  
output:
  pdf_document
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works nice.

Do you want to see this output?

[image]

---

Try this:

```
  \graphicspath{ {.\\pictures\\} }
  \fancyhead[]{\includegraphics[width=3 cm]{pic.png}}
```

---

Comment: I want to get current working directory for specifying the image location

Comment: I add nothing to your code. Did you choose working directory with ```setwd("C:\\MyDirectory\\R")```?

Comment: No. I wanted it to automatically detect the current working directory and find the image which will be present in tht directory

Comment: @james your solution works right. Where is a problem? If it doesn't work for you(?)  can try to use relative path. I added to answer.

Comment: Yes. I want to specify only relative path instead of absolute path.  So it should be \graphicspath{ {.\pic.png} } ?

Comment: @james No, look above. But without ```\graphicspath{ {.\\pictures\\} }``` it works right too ;)